# Cycles - How to turn off motion blur for multiple objects at once?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, motion-blur

I have hundreds of objects in my scene and I'd like to have motion blur on just one of them. I found this issue rather problematic because I only found the option to turn off motion blur per object.

Is there a way to turn them off in mass?

Comment: if you want to keep motion blur for one object only maybe you need to do it through the compositor

Comment: Motion blur is a global setting for the scene, not per-object. Render all of the objects, minus the blurry onr, in one scene. Render a scene with just the motion blurred one and composite together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all the objects on which you want to disable motion blur. In your case it may be easier to select the object you want to keep motion blur on and then hit cntrl i to invert selection.

Go to **object properties**  (looks like an orange square)

Go to **Motion Blur checkbox**

Uncheck motion blur for selected object

Right Click on check box and choose *Copy to Selected*

If done correctly, the disabled motion blur will transfer to all the other objects you had selected.

Comment: Thanks! This'll come handy in the future for sure!